# k-algebra homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

I have the following question and I don´t know how to answer it:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (or just an arbitrary field), and $A$ and $B$ two $k$-algebras. Let $A$ be a $B$-module too. I want to know under what circumstances we have a bijection between the following sets:
>   $$\operatorname{Hom}_{k-\rm{alg \hspace{0.1cm}grad}}(\operatorname{S}^{\bullet}_{B}A,k)=\operatorname{Hom}_{B-\rm{alg \hspace{0.1cm} grad}}(\operatorname{S}^{\bullet}_{B}A,B)\text{,}$$
>   where $\operatorname{S}^{\bullet}_{B}A$ is the symmetric algebra of $A$ as $B$-algebra. Here, $\operatorname{Hom}_{k-\rm{alg \hspace{0.1cm}grad}}$ stands for "set of homomorphisms of graded $k$-algebras".

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well... in this case we´ve putting the trivial graduation on $k$, that is $k=k\oplus 0\oplus 0\cdots$, so the homomorphisms would be just homomorphisms of $k$-algebras.

Comment: Ok. And with the symmetric algebra you mean [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+algebra#in_general). Did you try applying $G=\{ g \in Aut(A/k) , g|_B \in Aut(B/k)\}$ to $\rm{T}^{\bullet}_{B}A$ and $\rm{S}^{\bullet}_{B}A$ ? If $G$ is larger than $Aut(A/B)$ and $Hom(\rm{S}^{\bullet}_{B}A,B)$ is not trivial then

Comment: What do you mean by $\textit{applying}$?

Comment: It think $g\in G$ applies naturally to $a_1 \otimes_B \ldots \otimes_B a_n \in T^\bullet$ as well as to the quotient $S^\bullet$ and $Hom(S^\bullet ,.)$

Comment: I don´t understand what you are triying to prove using G. Could you be more specific?